# Isomorphism between maximal ideals in Boolean rings and homomorphisms into $\Bbb Z_2$ which are not identically zero

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, self-learning, boolean-algebra

This exercise **K** (f) of Chapter 2 from General Topology by Kelley.
I proved that there is exactly one  maximal ideal in the Boolean ring, but am stuck with showing that there is one homomorphism to $\Bbb Z_2$.

> *Preliminaries*
> The $\underline{natural\;ordering}$ of a Boolean ring is defined by agreeing that $r \geqslant s\; $ iff  $r\cdot s=s$;
> The $S$ is an ideal in a Boolean ring $(R,+,\cdot)$ iff $S$ is an additive subgroup and $r\cdot s \in S$ whenever $r\in R$ and $s\in S$;
> The ideal $S$ is maximal iff $R\neq S$ and no ideal other than $R$ properly contains $S$.

> *Problem*
> There is a one-to-one correspondence between maximal ideals in $R$ and homomorphisms into $\Bbb Z_2$ which are not identically zero.  $\;\;\;\;$(The kernel of such a homomorphism is a maximal ideal.).

*Proof:* Let $U,S$ be distinct maximal ideals in $R$, then their elements must be related by the natural ordering.
Suppose $\max(U) \leqslant \max(S)$, then $\max(U)\cdot \max(S)= \max(U)\in S$. So $U\subset S$. Hence there is only one maximal ideal.

On the other hand, suppose that $\varphi,\gamma$ are homomorphisms from Bool. ring $R$ on $\Bbb Z_2$. And let $s$ be element of max. ideal $S$ and $r\notin S$.
Then $\varphi(r\cdot s)=\varphi(s)=\varphi(r)\cdot\varphi(s) \implies\varphi(r)=1$.
Hence there is $s\in S$ s.t. $\varphi(s)=0$.
Likewise define $\gamma$ s.t. $\gamma(r)=1,\; \gamma(s)=0$ and  $\gamma(\max(S) :=q)=1$ for $r\geqslant q\geqslant s, \quad s\in S, r\notin S$
(I think that somehow following reasoning is in the direction of disproving $\gamma$)
Then $\gamma(r\cdot q)=\gamma(r)\cdot\gamma(q)=1\cdot\gamma(q)=1=\gamma(r)$.

Comment: You cannot prove that there is exactly one maximal ideal in a Boolean ring, because that is not true. Take $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$ - it's got two maximal ideals $\{(0,0),(0,1)\}$ and $\{(0,0), (1,0)\}$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop The proof relates to particular example above. You are right otherwise, should have written "*...proved that there is exactly one ideal in the boolean ring of the exercise...*".

Comment: Which exercise? The exercise (f) in Chapter 2 (K) is about an *arbitrary* Boolean ring $R$.

Comment: Your proof attempt is unclear to me - what is $\max(U)$? Do you know that it exists? How does $\max(U) \in S$ imply $U \subseteq S$? Also note that your natural ordering is not a linear order (two ring elements can be unrelated to each other) so even the other questions aside, you probably cannot assume $\max(U) \leq \max(S)$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Yes exactly. Let me ask about your example of two maximal ideals: How are $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ related in the natural ordering?

Comment: @DánielG OK, I assumed the order is linear like of natural numbers and since $r\cdot s$ is in $S$, I concluded that $r \leqslant s$, so $r\cdot s = s$.

Comment: ... Hence there is maximal element of an ideal $S$ and all elements of it are less than some $r\notin S$. Because if $r$ is an element of $S$ and it is not greatest, then there exists some element $s\in S:\;\; s\geqslant r$. Hence $s\cdot r=r$.

Comment: Boolean rings are ordered, as you could see in the book, but in general the ordering is not a *total* ordering - there would exist *incomparable* elements. For example, in $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$, $x=(1,0)$ and $y=(0,1)$ are incomparable: neither $x\le y$ nor $y\le x$.

Comment: Note with *partial* (not *total*) ordering there could be *maximal* elements (elements with no "bigger" than them) and still there may be no *maximum* (the "biggest of all" element) - and similar for "minimal element" vs. minimum. In my example, in the subset $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$, both of those elements are maximal (and minimal) but there is no maximum (nor minimum).

Comment: (However, my example is still relatively "tame" as both of those ideals *do* have a maximum  (they are "principal" ideals). For some infinite Boolean rings, certain ideals will not have a maximum.)

Comment: This all means, in terms of ordering you are better off forgetting your intuition from the rings such as $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb R$ and imagine Boolean rings as sort-of a generalisation of $\mathbb Z_2^n$, where comparison is component-wise: $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\le(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n)$ if and only if $x_1\le y_1,x_2\le y_2,\ldots,x_n\le y_n$.

Comment: @Stinking Very helpful, thanks.